# Background-position +/- X pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I offset the `background-position`, let's say 20px, from its original position?

**Like:**

```
$(".selector").animate("slow").css("backgroundPosition", "center -=20px");
```

(That obviously doesn't work... But how do I do this??)

Comment: what is .animate('slow') supposed to do?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078262/jquery-animate-background-position-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery by default does not animate backgrounds. There is this [short code](http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/jquery.bgpos.js) that can enable that. After you add it your code should work but first fix it like this:

```
$(".selector").animate({ "backgroundPosition": "center -=20px" },"slow");
```

Taken from:

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

Demo:

http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/

Answer (score 1):

Animating CSS `background-position` works with standard jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), as in [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5xs5S/2/).

#### HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

#### CSS

```
p {
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-image:url(http://lorempixum.com/200/50);
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('p').animate({'backgroundPosition':'-20px'}, 'slow');
```

Comment: 404 on the image; demo broken.

Comment: Argh, updated the demo but didn't edit link in post. Now fixed. Thanks for the comments @Tomalak

Answer (score 0):

You want to animate it or just change it?

You can change it by doing something like:

```
var newPos = parseFloat(($('.selector').css('backgroundPosition').replace('px', ''))+20) + "px";
$('.selector').css('backgroundPosition', newPos);
```