# jQuery background position doesn't work in FireFox?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery.animate background-position doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078262/jquery-animate-background-position-doesnt-work)

I have a small script that animates background positions, sadly it doesn't work in FireFox.
It works in IE and Chrome.

```
$('#background').animate({
     'background-position-x': -1020
});
```

How come it doesn't work in FireFox?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try out  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322347/jquery-1-6-backgroundposition-vs-backgroundpositionx-and-ff4-compatibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always create your own little plugin, it's not that hard.

Using jQuery 1.8 we now have access to the $.Animation method that gives us the animated values directly without to much work, so we can do something like :

```
$.fn.animateBG = function(x, y, speed) {
    var pos = this.css('background-position').split(' ');
    this.x = parseInt(pos[0]) || 0;
    this.y = parseInt(pos[1]) || 0;
    $.Animation( this, {
        x: x,
        y: y
      }, { 
        duration: speed
      }).progress(function(e) {
          this.css('background-position', e.tweens[0].now+'px '+e.tweens[1].now+'px');
    });
    return this;
}
```

And then to use it we can do:

```
$("#background").animateBG(x-value, y-value, speed);​
```

live example:
    $("#background").animateBG("0px", "-45px", 300);​

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HN3Ba/2/)

Disclaimer: This is not a finished and tested plugin, but something I spent ten minutes creating in jsFiddle, but test it out and do the changes you need to, and it should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378817/168735

> background-position-x is non standard CSS property and it is not supported by Firefox.
>
> See:
>
> http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175460/1011582

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out earlier, `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` are nonstandard.

There are two options you could explore:

1. jQuery background animation plugin (example: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/)
2. CSS3 transitions

Comment: The addon makes it work in FF (if you're using jQuery 1.7).  jQuery 1.8 messes up the whole concept of backgroundPosition it seems :(

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0130092789/ch14lev1sec7?portal=oreilly, this is a Internet Explorer CSS specific property.

Comment: How come it works in Chrome? And is there any other way to animate background position?

Comment: Because Chrome has copied a bunch of IE-specific stuff (including things like window.event for example).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox don't support `background-position-x` or `background-position-y`. You should write a simple function that calculate current x and y position, desired position and using `setTimeout` and `$(el).css` just animate it. Or use CSS3 animations.

P.S. 
Sorry, for my previous post.

Comment: Then again, animate does not accept two values !

Comment: Edited code, this should help you :) Use values in string

Comment: Do you even test this stuff before posting ?

Comment: adeneo - my bad, sorry for creating confusion untested funciton, I was to much sure it would be work and don't test it