# Did jQuery 1.8 break backgroundPosition animation?

Tags: jquery

I need to upgrade from jQuery 1.7 to jQuery 1.8, but the backgroundPosition animation is failing after the upgrade.  There are no error messages in the Firebug console at all.  Has anyone else had experience with the backgroundPosition animation failing from 1.7 to 1.8?

```
jQuery(navSelector).hover(function(){                   
      jQuery(this).find('a').stop().animate({"backgroundPosition":"(0 -40px)"},{duration:150});         
    },
    function(){             
      jQuery(this).find('a').stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, {duration:75});   
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you animate the x and y values separately?

Comment: This should have never worked at all. Anyway, just answered [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160846/jquery-background-position-doesnt-work-in-firefox/12161533#12161533)...

Comment: I should mention that, from what I understand, jQueryUI is actually responsible for this ever working in the first place.  There appears to be some discrepancy between jQuery 1.8 and jQueryUI 1.8 that didn't exist between jQuery 1.7 and jQueryUI 1.8.  I have tried JQUI 1.8.11 and 1.8.23 with no luck.  Likewise, I cannot animate each value separately.

Answer (score 1):

animate backgroundPosition has been broken since 1.5 - apparently it was never supposed to be in any of the releases

Answer (score 0):

The 1.8 version had many bugs, especially in IE9 & IE10. Download 1.8.1 and you should be good. Here's the changes: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 1.8.1 either.  Tested in Firefox and Chrome.  I should also say that it only worked in Firefox with jQuery 1.7 if you included the "backgroundPosition.js" addon.

Comment: Did you be sure to include Modernizr.js?

Answer (score 0):

It's not broken.. it works differently now

```
$arrow.animate({'background-position-x': '0px', 'background-position-y': '0px' }, 300);
```