# How to animate 'background-position' with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I was trying to animate `background-position` with jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nvv5b2dk/ `border-width` property animated perfectly but `background-position` didn't. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery background position doesn't work in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160846/jquery-background-position-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Opera and Firefox do not accept `background-position-x/y` animation. You can try to implement it using a custom plugin.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.background').animate({
    borderWidth: '1px'
  }).animateBG('0', '100px',300);
});

$.fn.animateBG = function(x, y, speed) {
    var pos = this.css('background-position').split(' ');
    this.x = parseInt(pos[0]) || 0;
    this.y = parseInt(pos[1]) || 0;
    $.Animation( this, {
        x: x,
        y: y
      }, { 
        duration: speed
      }).progress(function(e) {
          this.css('background-position', e.tweens[0].now+'px '+e.tweens[1].now+'px');
    });
    return this;
}
```

```css
.background {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/350x250);
  background-size: cover;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='background'></div>
<input type="button" class='btn' value="Button">
```

Comment: @NafeesAnwar which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using firefox 40.0.3

Comment: @NafeesAnwar See the updated answer. It is a complicated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('. background').animate({
  'background-position-x': '10%',
  'background-position-y': '20%'
}, 10000, 'linear');
```

According to this reference:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/