# Background image position change in jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the background image position in jquery animation. But my code is not working. Can any one help me to short it out.

Followings are my code

Css

```
#pnav a{
    background:url(http://www.us-bingo.com/images/Tickets/Solid-Color-Tyvek-Wrist-Tickets-lg.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:42px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('#pnav a')
.hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'background-position' : '(0px -42px)'
    }, 150);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'background-position' : '(0 0)'
    }, 150);
});
```

html

```
<div id="pnav">
<a href="#">123</a>
</div>
```

this is the [Fiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/eg5zC/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i guess , you might not have included your script inside document.ready. that's why it is getting called when the document is not ready. I've updated my code. and its a simple html. its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Background image position animation we need to use "jquery.backgroundpos.js" You can download it from here http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.backgroundpos.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#pnav a')
.hover(function () {
   $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px ' + '35px'}, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px ' + '0px'}, 500);
});


});
```

here is the updated [jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/eg5zC/11/)

Answer (score 4):

I think that jQuery animation can't animate `background-position`, but you can use CSS transitions instead

```
    #pnav a{
    background:url(http://www.us-bingo.com/images/Tickets/Solid-Color-Tyvek-Wrist-Tickets-lg.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:42px;

    -webkit-transition: background-position 150ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position 150ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-position 150ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-position 150ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-position 150ms ease-in-out;
}

#pnav a:hover {
    background-position:0px -42px;

}
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/eg5zC/7/
and the `transition` browser combatibility : http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

Comment: I think you forgot to click on 'Update' in your fiddle, however your approach does work

Comment: Also jQuery can animate background-position - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078298/16959, however jsfiddle seems to interfere with demonstrating this

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with this ,

```
background:url('http://www.us-bingo.com/images/Tickets/Solid-Color-Tyvek-Wrist-Tickets-lg.gif') no-repeat ;
```

Add inverted commas for URL in CSS

Comment: you don't need to put quotes around url's in CSS

Answer (score 0):

inside animate function, background-position doesn't work like that. use this instead

```
$('#pnav a')
.hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'background-position-x': '10%',
        'background-position-y': '20%'
    }, 550);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
       'background-position-x': '0%',
       'background-position-y': '0%'
    }, 550);
});
```

:[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position)

however, what you want can be achieved through CSS3.0 as 'xpy' pointed out, but it won't run on IE

## Update:

below is working sample:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#pnav a')
                    .hover(function () {
                        $(this).animate({
                            'background-position-x': '10%',
                            'background-position-y': '20%'
                        }, 550);
                    }, function () {
                        $(this).animate({
                           'background-position-x': '0%',
                           'background-position-y': '0%'
                        }, 550);
                    });
            });
        </script>
       <style>
            #pnav a{
                background:url(http://www.standard-icons.com/stock-icons/standard-road/scooter-icon.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
                display:block;
                width:20px;
                height:42px;
            }
       </style>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="pnav">
              <a href="#">123</a>
           </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/jt3we/)

Comment: hey sonasish, i made this out of your fiddle itself, and it was working for me. you might wanna adjust co-ordinate values, otherwise its pretty simply right??

Comment: can you please provide your fiddle file link?

Comment: its working on fiddle because, they make sure of document.ready, but your original code might not have it. anyways. uplinking fiddle in a moment